# fetch first element of every string in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like :

```
["ds","1:0,1,2,3,4","2:0,2,3,4,5","3:0,6,7,8,9"]
```

I want to fetch elements such that it has:

`[1:0,2:0,3:0]` (only the first element of every string in array leaving the `ds` element)

Please suggest a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a `forEach` to loop through the array and `split` using ','.

```js
var arr = ["ds", "1:0,1,2,3,4", "2:0,2,3,4,5", "3:0,6,7,8,9"];
var newArr = [];
arr.forEach(function(el,index) {
  if(index!=0)
  newArr.push(el.split(',')[0]);
});
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: And you down voted my answer because?

Answer (score -1):

```
var newarray = [];

oldarray.splice(0,1);
oldarray.forEach(function (element) {
  newarray.push(element.split(",")[0]);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr = ["ds","1:0,1,2,3,4","2:0,2,3,4,5","3:0,6,7,8,9"];

var newArr = arr.slice(1, arr.length).map(function (el) {
 return el.split(',')[0];
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [array `.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example):

```js
var input = ["ds","1:0,1,2,3,4","2:0,2,3,4,5","3:0,6,7,8,9"]

var output = input.reduce(function(acc, str) {
  var val = str.match(/^\d+:\d+/)
  if (val) acc.push(val[0])
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

When processing each element you could say `if (str != "ds")` or skip the first element based on its index, and then use `str.split(",")[0]` or some combination of `.slice()` or `.substr()` and `.indexOf()` or whatever, but I've chosen to use a regex `/^\d+:\d+/` with the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check if each input element contains the `digits:digits` structure at the beginning - that way it really doesn't matter what order the elements are in or what other arbitrary values might exist, it only uses elements that match the required pattern.